# Occasionally closed Devices tab in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

While developing my application in Eclipse, I occasionally closed
**Devices** tab in DDMS. So, I can't choose devices any more.

How can I return this tab back?

---

Already found answer:

**Window -> Show View -> Others -> ... Android -> Devices**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the perspective you would like the view...

Window>Show View>Other...>Android>Devices

[image]